# Combinations of numbers from the input array that add up to 14

Tags: python, arrays

I'm try to get the output as below like getting of the hash array, but
my code is not working correct. Please advise with the code.

The code should return 3 sets, as there are 3 combinations of numbers
from the input array that add up to 14, namely:

```
[2]          => input[2] = 14 
[0, 3]       => input[0] = 4, input[3] = 10, sum = 14 
[1, 3]       => input[1] = 4, input[3] = 10, sum = 14
```

This is running on Linux server with Python 2.7.5.

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target: 
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    subset_sum([4,4,14,10],14)
```

I expect the output to be:

```
[2]          => input[2] = 14
[0, 3]       => input[0] = 4, input[3] = 10, sum = 14
[1, 3]       => input[1] = 4, input[3] = 10, sum = 14
```

But the actual output:

```
sum([4, 10])=14
sum([4, 10])=14
sum([14])=14
```

Comment: thats because your partial array has the values, not the indices.

Comment: You need to store the position in the original list. As you are cutting down the list in each iteration you need to keep track of how many items you have already cut with an offset.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate or help adjust to code?